# AjaxCall Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, basic-authentication

I am trying to make an Ajax call as follows:

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        username: "user",
        password: "admin",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/projects/1",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
       },
        success: function(data){     
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

But I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
```

Am I missing something? (Authentication on the endpoint is HTTPBasicAuthorization)

Comment: you don't need http://localhost:8080/ , you should just need /projects/1 for your url

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need to do it like this:

Full code:

```
headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
  },
```

Full code:

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/projects/1",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username+ ":" + password)
        },
        success: function(data){     
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

If that doesn't work, then this should work:

```
 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
},
```

Comment: second one error:    `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRequestHeader' of undefined
    at beforeSend`